# MySQL Full Text Search on columns with special characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MySQL column that contains a character like 's (eg. lee's).  When performing Full text search "lee" on the column does not return any results.  Search including "'s" (e.g. "lee's") takes a long time to return a huge number of results.

How does MySQL Full text search handle a character like "'s" and what's the best way to make search on this type's column work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Search depends on the definition of the collation used, whether the particular character you are considered about is considered a punctuation character or a letter character. With MyISAM, the apostrophe should be considered a character in a word, not punctuation.

There's a bug report with InnoDB Full Text Search regarding the apostrophe; it's not clear whether you are using MyISAM or InnoDB.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69216)

And again, it really depends on the collation used, how an apostrophe is handled.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html